# Filtering a list of objects without linq c#

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of objects called images which are obtained from parsing through a text file. They contain details such as the catagory and description. I want to be able to search through the list to find the images with a certain catagory and then display them on a form i have setup. I want to filter through them and then also be able to revert back to the unfiltered view aswell.

```
class Image
{
    public string FileName { set; get; }
    public string Description { set; get; }
    public string Catagory { set; get; }
    public string Date { set; get; }
    public string Comments { set; get; }
}
```

This is what i want to do in Linq

```
string chosenCatagory = CatagoryComboBox.Text;

ImageList = ImageList.Where(x => x.Catagory == chosenCatagory).ToList();
```

What would be the best way to approach this without using Linq?

Answer (score 4):

You can use List's [`FindAll`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fh1w7y8z(v=vs.85).aspx) method:

```
ImageList = ImageList.FindAll(x => x.Catagory == chosenCatagory);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, next thing is how can i revert back to the unfiltered view as well after filtering it?

Answer (score 0):

Use two Lists. ImageList which contains all data and DisplayList which is filled only with the stuff you want to display.

```
DisplayList = ImageList.FindAll(x => x.Catagory == chosenCatagory);
```

And if you want to revert set DisplayList back to ImageList.

```
DisplayList = ImageList;
```

Also have a look at [CollectionView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.collectionview?view=netframework-4.7.1) when you wanna do more advanced stuff. It supports filtering, grouping and sorting.